# ElasticSearch, search the max ID from an Asset

Tags: elasticsearch, search, assets

I have a problem to find a max-value from an asset. My problem is to find the max-value of the ImageId.

```
{
    "_index": "b885a88d-7f55-5841-8166-77c948cff307",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "0a714077-83c0-4d5f-a1d5-88b3f3689b34",
    "_version": 2,
    "_seq_no": 5443,
    "_primary_term": 1,
    "found": true,
    "_source": {
        "created": "2020-01-31T15:01",
        "assetId": "0a714077-83c0-4d5f-a1d5-88b8f3689b34",
        "properties": [
            {
                "uuid": "e2f9e990-aa6e-4122-87fb-1b98307d7d58",
                "name": "imageId",
                "namespace": "file.Jpeg",
                "value": "123456"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "bc506442-90a6-41fc-a36b-2970f202988d",
                "name": "tmpName",
                "namespace": "file.Jpeg",
                "value": "/tmp/phpQIqVPk"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "6b3a2624-adf3-449b-a6c9-883396f98538",
                "name": "type",
                "namespace": "file.Jpeg",
                "value": "image/jpeg"
            },
            {
                "uuid": "3cf1be43-d0e8-4bb1-8c16-6f05a99d55f6",
                "name": "size",
                "namespace": "file.Jpeg",
                "value": "6605"
            },
        ],
        "asset_child_references": [],
        "asset_parent_references": []
    }
}
```

**I tried this one**:

```
{"query":{"match":{"properties.name":"imageId"}},
"sort": [
    {
      "properties.value": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
   "size": 1
}
```

but it checks every value parameter. How can I check only the value parameter from the imageId?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Array in Elasticsearch must be nested.

I found this on Elsaticsearch:

> Arrays of objects do not work as you would expect: you cannot query each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you need to be able to do this then you should use the nested datatype instead of the object datatype.

Now i have nested my data.

```
    {
        "mappings": {
            "properties": {
                "properties": {
                    "type": "nested" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this will help other user :-)